# autobreak/allowframebreaks/allowpagebreaks problem in long Org+Beamer file when exporting to long slides

Tags: beamer, org-mode

(1) I’d like to use an long Emacs + Org-mode + Beamer file (.org) to export a long slide. The .org file is about 100 pages, the slide will goto about 500 pages. So I would like to make the export directly by the .org file and not insert/modify the output .tex file.

(2) However, I met the auto-break problem when I tried to export it.
(3) I used the command of: M-x org-beamer-export-to-pdf  to generate the slide

(4) The configuration in the front of my .org file is as follow:

```
#+TITLE:  A long content Org-mode Beamer PPT export test

#+AUTHOR: test                      

#+LaTeX_CLASS_OPTIONS:[presentation,professionalfonts,compress,smaller,aspectratio=169]  

#+BEAMER_HEADER:\institute{test}                                               

#+PROPERTY: comments yes                                                                                          

#+PROPERTY: header-args :exports both :eval never-export 

#+BEAMER_COLOR_THEME: default                                                                                                  

#+BEAMER_THEME:CambridgeUS                                                                                             

#+BEAMER_INNER_THEME: default                                                               

#+COLUMNS: %45ITEM %10BEAMER_ENV(Env) %10BEAMER_ACT(Act) %4BEAMER_COL(Col)                            

#+LATEX_HEADER:\usepackage{xeCJK,fontspec,xunicode,xltxtra}                                                                 

#+LATEX_HEADER:\setCJKmainfont[Scale=0.98]{Yuanti SC Light}                                                                   

#+LATEX_HEADER: \AtBeginSection[]{\begin{frame}<beamer>\frametitle{Topic}\tableofcontents[currentsection]\end{frame}}

#+BEAMER_HEADER: \definecolor{links}{HTML}{0000A0}                                                                    

#+BEAMER_HEADER: \hypersetup{colorlinks=,linkcolor=,urlcolor=links}                                                  

#+BEAMER_HEADER: \setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[default]                                                                    

#+BEAMER_HEADER: \setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[default]                                                       

#+BEAMER_HEADER: \setbeamertemplate{items}[default]                                                                        

#+BEAMER_HEADER: \setbeamercolor*{local structure}{fg=darkred}                                                        

#+BEAMER_HEADER: \setbeamercolor{section in toc}{fg=darkred}                                                                 

#+BEAMER_HEADER: \setlength{\parskip}{\smallskipamount}                                                                     

#+OPTIONS:H:3 num:t toc:t \n:nil @:t ::t |:t ^:t -:t f:t *:t <:t
```

(1) I have tried to put

`allowframebreaks` in  `#+LaTeX_CLASS_OPTIONS:`, `#+OPTIONS:`, `#+latex_header:`. All of them do not work

(2) I have tried to insert:

```
:PROPERTIES:

:BEAMER_opt: allowframebreaks,label=

:END:
```

after each section, subsection, subsubsection title. Just part of the content can work and broke into the following slide, the rest were not work properly.

(3) Even I can not get the table- of-content displayed on the front of the Slide in this configuration

(4) I tried to delete `:eval never-export` in `#+PROPERTY`, but still not work

Thanks a lot!

Comment: anyone could help to check it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

From  https://github.com/fniessen/refcard-org-beamer

```
** A very long "frame" with breaks
:PROPERTIES:
:BEAMER_opt: allowframebreaks,label=
:END:
```

Works just fine for me for bibliographies and similar sections

Answer (score 1):

From https://github.com/fniessen/refcard-org-beamer - the relevant option is this:

```
#+BIND: org-beamer-frame-default-options "allowframebreaks"
```

Comment: thanks... However，I have tried the #+BIND option. and is still not work... more ideas?

Comment: @saga `(setq org-export-allow-bind-keywords t)`